# Whats WRONG with this bash script[mysql-query]

Tags: mysql, bash, insert

The first query works fine, but the second query doesn't work.. why? What's wrong?

```
#/bin/bash
MyUSER="root"     # USERNAME
MyPASS="pass"       # PASSWORD
MyHOST="localhost"          # Hostname
DBS="$(mysql -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS mydbname -Bse 'select `id` from `table` where `reset`=1 and `status`=0')"
if [ $DBS > 0 ];  then
    STRR='UPDATE `restart` SET `status` = 1 WHERE `id` ='$DBS' '
    DBS2="$(mysql -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS proftpd -e '$STRR')"
fi
```

FIXED ! Thanks.

Fixed version:

```
if [ $DBS > 0 ];  then
    DBS2="$(mysql -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS proftpd -e 'UPDATE `restart` SET `status` = 1 WHERE `id` ='$DBS'')"
fi
```

Comment: Is `if [ $DBS > 0 ]` supposed to be a greater-than test? If so, it needs to be `if [ $DBS -gt 0 ]` or `if (( DBS > 0 ))`. Otherwise it creates a file named "0" and is probably always true. If, on the other hand you want to test the exit value of the first query, it should be `if [ $? = 0 ]` to test for success or `if [ $? != 0 ]` to test for failure.

Answer (score 0):

You write your Select query result into "DBS" but then you use $DBS for your if-condition. Maybe that's why the second doesn't get executed.

A little more information would be nice.

Comment: Wow. Fixed:

if [ $DBS > 0 ];  then
DBS2="$(mysql -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS proftpd -e 'UPDATE `restart` SET `status` = 1 WHERE `id` ='$DBS'')"
fi

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if [ $DBS > 0 ];  then

DBS2="$(mysql -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS proftpd -e 'UPDATE `restart` SET `status` = 1 WHERE `id` ='$DBS'')"

fi